# Sitecore Azure deployment error - Sitecore.Azure.UI.Pipelines.PreAutomation.CheckHostedService failed

Tags: deployment, azure, cloud

I'm attempting to deploy an 8.2 site to Azure. In the Sitecore Azure tool, when I deploy to the Local Emulator, the web files are partially copied to the package location and the long error below is thrown. xDB Cloud config files are disabled. The deployment to the Azure cloud environment also fails with a "Sitecore.Azure.UI.Pipelines.PreAutomation.CheckHostedService failed" error, but one step at a time. 
I'm running SC 8.2, Azure SDK v. 2.9 (also tried 2.7.1). 
The site runs fine in IIS 8.5.

> ManagedPoolThread #10 16:31:01 ERROR Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployAndRun.DevFabric.CreatePackage,Sitecore.Azure,Process
>   Exception: System.Exception
>   Message: Job started: DevFabricDeploy|xDB Cloud Edition Configuration is failed|Create package is failed|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.CreateAzurePackage.Azure.XDBCloudEditionChanges.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase args)
>      at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase args)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>      at Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
>      at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.DeployAndRun.DevFabric.CreatePackage.StartPipeline(AzureRolePipelineArgs args, CreateAzureDeploymentPipelineArgs deploymentArgs)
>      at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase args)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>      at Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
>      at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.PipelineJobManager.Worker(Pipeline pipeline, PipelineArgs pipelineArgs)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Comment: I really can't help you with this error, but I would advise you to wait until Sitecore 8.2.1: some automated azure deployment scripts are delivered with that release, which will make your life a LOT easier. It will work with Webroles, adds the different Sitecore roles to each node, adds azure search, redis, application insights and so forth.

Comment: As @BasLijten said as well, I'd wait until 8.2 update 1. In addition to that, I just wanted to point out that 8.2 using the Azure module is technically not supported (see https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Azure Module has been deprecated from Sitecore 8.2.  We will be updating the module for 8.1 to support; new Azure SQL and SDK and most important change to Redis Cache Session State Provider (as the In-Role Cache service being shut down end of November).

The new Sitecore Cloud offering will be launched with Sitecore 8.2 update 1. Using ARM (Azure Resource Manager) Templates, Azure Web Apps, Application Insights, Azure Search and Redis Cache.

As @BasLijten and @Trayek mention I strongly recommend you to wait on SC 8.2 update 1, it's going to be really cool in the cloud :)

Comment: Can't wait, for the new azure updates!

Comment: Is there a release window for 8.2.1?

Comment: The release date has not been communicated. 

The release has been announced and presented including a demo on  Symposium. I can't give you any dates, but the demo of the release was really solid and quiet final. :)

Comment: cant wait .. wont wait :) !!